# Condition in a theorem in Probability theory.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I passed by a simple theorem in Probability theory , yet it really bugs me that I think that 1 condition in the hypothesis is not necessary. 
After checking the proof for many times, I still can't understand author's intention .

Can any one help me by giving me a proper answer?

*The Theorem.

"Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s Let g,h be continuous functions with:

i) $g \ge 0 ; g(x) \rightarrow  \infty $ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$

ii) $\frac{|h(x)|}{g(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as$ |x| \rightarrow \infty$, and,

iii) $Eg(X_n)\le K < \infty \forall n$

Then $Eh(X_n) \rightarrow Eh(X)$"

*My Question

Is  the condition  "$g(x) \rightarrow  \infty $ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$" necessary? Why?

*The provided Proof.

[image]

-Durett R.,Probabability Theory and Examples, 2010, page 30

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The author uses one property which is implied by $g(x) \to \infty$ for $|x| \to \infty$, namely that there is $M>0$ with $g(x) > 0$ for all $|x| \geq M$.

But apart from that, this assumption is not used.

But observe that if $g$ is bounded (this is **not** the same as $g(x) \not \to \infty$ for $|x|\to\infty$, though), the claim is more or less trivial, because with (ii) this yields that $h$ is bounded, so that

$$
\Bbb{E}(h(X_n)) \to \Bbb{E}(h(X))
$$

follows trivially by continuity of $h$ and dominated convergence.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer and your time.